# Initialising MatPaginator asynchronously

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-material

We initialise MatPaginator in our `components` like

`@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;`

and assign to a `MatTable DataSource` defined in our component as

`matTableDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;`

This doesn't work in a use case when the data source is initialised asynchronously using `async` pipe with a combination of `*ngIf`. As,

```
<div *ngIf="someDataObs | async as yourData else loading">
   <mat-table #table [dataSource]="yourData">
      ... your headers and columns
   </mat-table>
   <mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**Note**: you could put `mat-paginator` below the `div` with `*ngIf`, but that's not an ideal solution, more so if you need to show multiple tables in a same component coming with a single backend asynchronous call.

Since the `mat-paginator` will get initialised asynchronously, using a code such as below will not work as `paginator` will be `null`.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.someDataObs = this.backendService.get()
    .map(value => {
      const matTableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SomeType>(value);
      matTableDataSource.paginator = this.paginator; // will be null here
      return matTableDataSource;
    });
}
```

To have a way for this to work would've required `MatPaginator` to have an `output property` to emit once initialised, but that doesn't exist for now.

Use of `async` pipe and `*ngIf` makes the code really concise and you should not avoid it to overcome this use case.

Any solution to achieve this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.This is a known problem and they  have solved this, in my opinion, better.

```
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator( paginator: MatPaginator){
   this.dataSource.paginator = paginator;
 }
 @ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort( sort: MatSort){
   this.dataSource.sort = sort;
 }
```

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10205#issuecomment-465455599

Answer (score 0):

Endeed, your problem is the *ngIf.

With `@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator`, when paginator is requested, it is not found in the DOM and it return null.

A solution to this problem, is to replace your *ngIf by a statement with `display:none`. So the paginator will stay in the DOM.

Comment: Exactly, I know it will be null until the `afterViewInit()`. Using something like `[hidden]` property or your solution is not ideal and moreover we want it to work with `async` pipe.

Comment: This is a known problem. Check this issue:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10205

Comment: That solution is a workaround, by applying `@ViewChild` on the setter, you need a separate component variable for the `datasource` along with the `observable` which somewhat defies the purpose of using `async` pipe.

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround because there is no clean solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10205) solution and it works fine

Just add this *ngIf="pagination" to your mat-paginator in HTML:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  ......

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons 
*ngIf="pagination" > <!-- THIS!!! -->
</mat-paginator>
```

And then add this estructure to your component

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
@Input('pagination') pagination: boolean;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator,  {static: false}) set matPaginator(paginator: 
MatPaginator) {
  if (this.pagination) {
    this.dataSource.paginator = paginator;
  }
}
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10205):

Just add this HIDDEN before the table
While HIDDEN==TRUE the table will not be rendered before the dataSource is loaded:

```
<div [hidden]="isLoading">
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  ...
  </mat-table>
</div>
```