# Angular Material Paginator is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, paginator

I use Angular Material (MatTable, MatPaginator).
when i log in to my application and my component view is loaded, i get the following error in my browser debugger:

```
    ERROR TypeError: "_this._paginator is undefined; can't access its "pageIndex" property"

    ExampleDataSource http://localhost:4200/main.js:1446
    __tryOrUnsub http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:160732
    next http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:160670
    _next http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:160603
    next http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:160578
    _subscribe http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:159751
    _trySubscribe http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:159963
    _trySubscribe http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:160384
```

my goal is to get rid of this error.

as there is too much code that could be responsible for this error, please see my component at my Github: https://github.com/chrs-k/Behaeltermanagement/tree/master/Behaeltermanagement/client/src/app/table

The problem must be located in the table.component.ts

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: angular version?

Comment: "@angular/cli": "~6.1.5",

Comment: Stackblitz will help in this case!

Comment: thanks for your comment. i can build it successfully too. i also don't get an error with the ng live server. but my browser debugger shows the error mentioned above. everything works, i just don't want to have this error :). i guess i have to initialize the paginator in  ngAfterViewInit(), but don't really know how. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462568/initialising-matpaginator-asynchronously

Comment: hmm look for official document!

Comment: I want to go there but I don't have the server up, what is the route?  Are there route guards up?

Comment: no route guard implemented yet. your answer posted below already solved it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paginator is marked with @ViewChild, and thus will not be loaded until ngAfterViewInit() is called.  However, you put an instance of constructing a new ExampleDataSource inside loadData(), which is called in ngOnInit.  **But according to the order of Angular lifestyle hook methods, ngOnInit() will be called before ngAfterViewInit().**  You have called it at least twice already before ngAfterViewInit()!  So put this.loadData() into ngAfterViewInit, and up top you should have

```
dataSource: ExampleDataSource;
```

Remove anything that depends on this.paginator to instead be in ngAfterViewInit.